# Generic that modifies a type's property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In TypeScript (4.5.2), I'm trying to create a generic that takes a type and modifies some of its properties.

```
type StrictNumber = {
  doesNotChange: string,
  nullable: false,
  value: number,
};

type MakeNullable<T extends { nullable: false, value: unknown }> = {
  [Property in keyof T]: Property extends 'nullable'
    ? true
    : Property extends 'value'
      ? T[Property] | null
      : T[Property]
};

type NullableNumber = MakeNullable<StrictNumber>;
```

Here's the resulting type for `NullableNumber`:

```
type NullableNumber = {
  doesNotChange: string,
  nullable: true,
  value: number | null,
};
```

Which is exactly what I want. However the `MakeNullable` generic is really not an elegant solution, it's very verbose. It would be even more if I added more properties to modify.

Comment: Have you considered just use `&` intersection ? I mean `StrictNumber & {nullable: true}`

Comment: This gives me `type NullableNumber = never`, I'm not sure why. But anyways, the `value` property, that has to be modified as well, has to be modified in a dynamic fashion (`number` becomes `number | null`) so this wouldn't work. Note that I intend to use `MakeNullable` with multiple types (e.g. with `StrictString`).

Comment: my bad, `true & false` evaluates to `never`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could infer the `value` type using [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types):

```
type MakeNullable<T extends { nullable: false, value: unknown }> = T extends { value: infer V }
    ? { nullable: true, value: V | null } : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAxsAcgVwLYCMLygF4oBvAWACgpqoA7DAGwYEMcGIAuKAM2YYGcIAGko0oANz4ZOdbHngiKAXwDclSqEhQAsswDWETE1bsAPABUoEAB7AItACb9Ss42xm8BwiVJkZaerQA9gDutFBKAHxEUJY2do7OJK4s7lyegkI+DNJciLTc+FAAahGiNAD8LvRu7FwI0lmSOTKlAD4pEVBctBDi+GoUGuDQRqnsmLhFxLoGYyYQpnBIqJPykSpAA)

---

If you want to carry over all additional properties, you can make an intersection with original type, but [omitting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) the modified properties:

```
type MakeNullable<T extends { nullable: false, value: unknown }> = T extends { value: infer V }
    ? Omit<T, 'nullable' | 'value'> & { nullable: true, value: V | null } : never;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAxsAcgVwLYCMLygF4oBvAWACgpqoA7DAGwYEMcGIAuKAM2YYGcIAGko0oANz4ZOdbHngiqNYBH7AuapLQDmlAL4BuSpVCQoAWWYBrCJiat2AHgAqUCAA8VtACb9Ss%20zYZXgFhCSkZDForWgB7AHdaKD0APiIoVw8vX396QPYuEMEhcIZpLkRabnwoADVk0RoAfigAeSxEYBcSgHI8liCeqAAfKB7JMogetIAyXMYBgqgEaRKJ8rqRgIZkqC5aCHF8IwoTcGg7Rds5GuJLG0uHCEc4JFRMXHwUk8pkWNo1DxYrEuI8gh95OkSNsnlwVmF1jJ%20iUVGouD0hnogA)

---

Or even simpler (adjusted @captain-yossarian suggestion):

```
type MakeNullable<T extends { nullable: false, value: unknown }> =
    Omit<T, 'nullable' | 'value'> & { nullable: true, value: T['value'] | null }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAxsAcgVwLYCMLygF4oBvAWACgpqoA7DAGwYEMcGIAuKAM2YYGcIAGko0oANz4ZOdbHngiqNYBH7AuapLQDmlAL4BuSpQD0JqKEhQAsswDWETE1bsAPABUoEAB4raAE35SWWc2GV4BYQkpGQxaO1oAewB3Wig9AD4iKE8fP0DgyQZpLkRabnwoADV003MxAH4oAHksRGAPISgAcnpQ9m6oAB8eoulurIAyYL6WMK4EaS6xmRqR2fSoLloIcXwjCkpLaFsHJzm3XN8IAKCSEIvwvkFlmK44hJS0zKJRGlb2p0erMXBBBiNuisJlBpvcQfMLPAltFijJ3ABtSExboAXWGD1qhwoxyg51BmFwlWIp0cjEerjgSFQFPkGQOlGQiVoah4iUSXDJYRZVJmdNBCyRURW2zpXRUai43UGeiAA)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but, doing this, I'll loose all the other properties that `T` might have. I want `nullable` and `value` to be modified, but the other properties to remain the same. I should have added a fixed property in my example to emphasise that. I'll do it right now.

Comment: Thanks for that second snippet that indeed fixes the problem of lost properties. It's definitely a good option. I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer just in case someone shows up with an even less verbose solution.

Comment: Added simpler option, that's actually what @captain-yossarian suggested just with omitting modified props so it won't resolve to `never`.

Comment: It's even better yes. But any idea why the type does not show up as expected when hovering `NullableNumber` in your playground?

Comment: You can use "re-map" hack to print it https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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